# 22.04 LTS - GPU Decoding Library Failed to Load

Tags: drivers, dell

I am fairly new to Ubuntu. We have some Exacqvision camera software that is running fine on Ubuntu 19, but when installing a newer version on a Dell Latitude E5470 (5 years old) I get the error when loading that the GPU Decoding Library failed to load so it cannot show cameras.

I followed this [link](https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu/) to update the video drivers for my Intel Mesa and rebooted, but still seeing the same error.

I don't get the error on my 11 year old Dell Latitude E6520. It worked out of the box.

Is the GPU Decoding Library part of Ubuntu?

Comment: If you know the path to the software's executable program you can use the `ldd` command to see what dynamic shared objects it is trying to load - that may throw some light on the issue

Comment: I used the ldd command with the -v option and it returned a large list. Is there a method to tell which one is bad? Nothing is sticking out with a graphics or GPU name. I am also not seeing anything that is "not found" or "not loaded" in the list.

Comment: OK so if you're not seeing any "not found" messages then I guess ldd is not helpful in this instance - sorry